# full HTML of object returned by jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

given this html:

```
<li id="the_list_item"><img src="some_img"></li>
```

and this selectior:

```
$("#the_list_item")
```

I want to get the full html from the object return by the jQuery selector.

Using:

```
$("#the_list_item").html()
```

...just gives me the inner html (the `<img src="some_img">` part)

But since:

```
$("#the_list_item").attr("id")
```

gives me 'the_list_item', this indicated that the whole list item is indeed included in the object returned.. so how do I get the full code from that object?

I want to get a String: `<li id="the_list_item"><img src="some_img"></li>` from my object, but can't find the way to do it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One way is to create your own wrapper:

```
$("#the_list_item").wrap('<div>').parent().html();
```

...do your thing, then unwrap:

```
$("#the_list_item").unwrap();
```

Comment: I've changed the accepted answer because of the better cross browser compatibility of this one, though it's a terrible hacky approach.. but this does seem to be the approach most agree on.

Comment: If you want to avoid affecting the original element in any way, you can clone it before wrapping it: `$("#the_list_item").clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();`

Comment: @tobuslieven Things have changed enough in the five years since I wrote the original answer that I'd generally recommend outerHTML at this point, as in the answer from Tatu Ulmanen below. ([See: CanIUse outerHTML](http://caniuse.com/#search=outerhtml)). The caveat, as always, is IE, and specifically IE8, so if you must support old IE you'd still need a wrapper approach like one of the above.

Answer (score 32):

I'm not sure if this works, but it might be worth a shot:

```
var html = $('#the_list_item')[0].outerHTML;
alert(html);
```

```js
var html = $('#the_list_item')[0].outerHTML;
console.log(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="the_list_item"><img src="some_img"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is elegant.. will it work in all browsers? it does work in Safari.

I found out that dumping the object (in my case a jQuery ui.draggable) to the Safari Dev console:

    console.log(ui.draggable);

revealed the total skeleton of this jQuery object, and it looks like an array (though it is an object) and it has something like another object at index 0, which has a outerHTML property that holds the entire html string.. so yes, using $('#the_list_item')[0].outerHTML or in my case ui.draggable[0].outerHTML rturns exactly what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 11):

Leaving just in case someone nowadays is still looking for this.
Full jQuery solution:

```
$('#the_list_item').prop('outerHTML');
```

Answer (score 3):

Here my solution, No jQuery required!

```
// Get a reference to the element by its ID.
var oEl = document.getElementById('the_list_item');
// Getting the outerHTML of an element:
var sOuterHTML = oEl.outerHTML;
 alert( sOuterHTML );
```

Alternatively, it could be get the reference of element by means of jQuery, and then get the outerHTML.

```
var sOuterHTML = $('#the_list_item')[0].outerHTML;
alert( sOuterHTML );
// or
var  sOuterHTML = $('#the_list_item').get(0).outerHTML;
alert( sOuterHTML );
```

Comment: outerHTML is the best and most clean solution if it can be used. However, it doesn't have full support in IE8/9. I needed that at the time I wrote this question. http://caniuse.com/#search=outerHTML

Answer (score 2):

There's no "outer html" equivalent in jQuery, but this might help:
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-get-full-html-string-including.html

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the outerHTML solution (accepted solution above) did not work for me on FireFox 9 / Windows 7 / JQuery 1.7 ...

Here is something that worked for me, according to Chetan Sastry (answer above):

```
var el = jQuery('#the_list_item').first();
var outerHtml = jQuery('<div>').append(el).html();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `$("#the_list_item").parent().html()`?

Comment: Works only if the parent has only this element and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a nice solution in the form of the code for a jQuery outerHtml plugin: http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new div DOM object and appending a clone of the div, then get the contents of wrapped div and finally removing the created DOM object.

```
var html = $('<div>').append($('#the_list_item').clone()).remove().html();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins for that. Just google for "jQuery outerhtml". The idea behind most of them is to clone the element, append it to an empty div and get that div's html.