# jQuery console.log() vs alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

jQuery code:

```
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    alert(e.target);
});
```

The `e.target` contains the name of the object which is being clicked. 
For demonstration purposes, if I click on an input element, the above code prints the following : 
For `console.log()`:

```
<input class="buton" type="submit" value="Send" name="Send">
```

For `alert()`:

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
```

However, if I replace `console.log(e.target)` with `console.log(e.target.toString())`, it prints the same thing as `alert()`, meaning:

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
```

My scope is to store the HTML code returned by `console.log()` into a variable, but I can't understand the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event handler, `e.target` is the element that the click originated from. Most browser consoles display this as the html string that represents the element.

When you use `alert`, the argument supplied is converted to a string, so you'll see `[object HTMLInputElement]`.

To get to the HTML of an element, use:

```
alert(e.target.outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` is useful when you want to see properties of an object, but `alert()` only shows the type of an object, if you want to see the real html of an element, you can use `outerHTML` property of the DOM Element object:

```
alert(e.target.outerHTML);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/phLVu/

Comment: How can I debug a variable, without `console.log`? Data type, values, everything stored within. Something like print_r() of PHP.

Comment: @Schutzstaffel There is no such method in JavaScript, You can use `for in` loop, and read the properties of an object, but using console.log is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

See this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535284/full-html-of-object-returned-by-jquery-selector) :

You have to use the `outerHTML` attribute.

```
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.target.outerHTML);
});
```

see the jsFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/xhHPb/

Comment: Please keep in mind that `outerHTML` is not an attribute of an element. It's a property. If you're using jQuery 1.6+, you'll want to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

The console tool displays an object in the way the designer thought was useful, it doesn't just call the `toString()` method of the object, contrary to `alert`.

If you want to get the HTML code of your target, simply do

```
var html = e.target.outerHTML;
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to wrap it with jQuery first before calling `html()`? Also, wouldn't `html()` return just the inner HTML? (instead of the whole thing)

Comment: Thanks! Learned about outerHTML too :-). Works!