# JavaScript: Change objectHTMLScriptElement

Tags: javascript

I am currently working within a CMS, cleaning up 12 websites.

Currently there are 12 identical JS files each residing within their respective site. Since they are all the same, my first initiative is to point every site to a single JS file that lives on the server.

Because I'm working within a CMS, I would have to open up 200 templates to accomplish this feat manually, so I'd, of course, rather do this dynamically.

Here is what I have done, so far:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName ("script");
console.log(scripts[15]);
```

My console.log statement returns what I'd like to replace, which is this:

```
<script src="/Assets/AmericanTower.com.br/uploads/content/js/main.js">
```

When I use alert(); rather than console.log(); I get this:

```
[object HTMLScriptElement]
```

I don't really understand why alert and console.log are showing me 2 different results.

So, I gather that I need to find a way to convert this HTMLElement to a string and then replace the string(or part of it) with the path to my new JS file.

Can anyone please shed some light?

Thank you in advance!

Robin

===============================

Thank you, L.C. Echo Chan, for your contribution. Here's how I used your suggestion and it worked like a charm!

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var jsPath=scripts[15].outerHTML;
var changedURL=jsPath.replace(jsPath,"RegionalGlobalAssets");    
alert(changedURL);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635582/jquery-console-log-vs-alert check this link

Comment: Using "Find and replace on disk" command on your editor/framework would be more robust solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using outerHTML property can return the entire element

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
alert(scripts[15].outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set you code as that

```js
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
console.log(scripts[15]);
```