# JQuery .html() usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Say I have

```
<div id="controller">
 <div id="first">1</div>
 <div id="second">2</div>
</div>
```

`$('#controller').html()`.which returns

```
<div id="first">1</div>
<div id="second">2</div>
```

How do I get `.html()` to return

```
<div id="controller">
 <div id="first">1</div>
 <div id="second">2</div>
</div>
```

Or is there an alternate function for that?

Comment: Have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4741203/1577396)

Comment: possible duplicate of [full HTML of object returned by jQuery selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535284/full-html-of-object-returned-by-jquery-selector)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it (ie. a clone) inside another parent

```
$('<div></div>').append($('#controller').clone()).html();
```

Also, check out a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [outerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/m86Ym/)**

```
$('#controller')[0].outerHTML
```

You can add your div's clone to dynamically created div and use html of it.

```
$('<div>').append($('#controller').clone()).html();
```

Comment: This is not cross browser, though